# Error to pass a .rpt report to .pdf using CrystalReportsNinja (w/ ORCL)

Tags: oracle, pdf, crystal-reports, rpt

Im using CrystalReportsNinja to make my .rpt report to .pdf, but isn't working.

Error:

```
29-05-2018  16:44:28    Report loaded successfully
29-05-2018  16:44:28    Output Filename : c:\CrystalReportsNinja\oracle.pdf
29-05-2018  16:44:28    Output format : pdf
29-05-2018  16:44:28    Exception: Falha de logon no banco de dados.
29-05-2018  16:44:28    Inner Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8004100F): Falha de logon no banco de dados.
   em CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass.Export(ExportOptions pExportOptions, RequestContext pRequestContext)
   em CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
```

Command Line to create report in pdf:

```
CrystalReportsNinja.exe -F “oracle.rpt” -l -U rptuser -P XXXXXX -O oracle.pdf -E “pdf” -S “(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=XX.XX.XX.XXX)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL)))”
```

Comment: it says: "Failed to log on to the database" - check your connection details

Comment: my connection parameters are right, but it still doesn't work